# Haskell: Algebric data types whose type variables need to be an instance of a typeclass

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism, typeclass

I am trying to define an algebric type:

```
data MyType t = MyType t
```

And make it an instance of Show:

```
instance Show (MyType t) where
  show (MyType x) = "MyType: " ++ (show x)
```

GHC complains becasue it cannot deduce that type 't' in 'Show (MyType t)' is actually an instance of Show, which is needed for (show x).

I have no idea where and how do I declare 't' to be an instance of Show?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add a type constraint on the type of `t`:

```
instance Show t => Show (MyType t) where
  show (MyType x) = "MyType: " ++ (show x)
```

Answer (score 15):

You could also just:

```
data MyType t = MyType t
    deriving Show
```

if you want a regular show format.

Answer (score 2):

A yet another solution is to use GADTs:

```
data MyType t  where 
   MyType :: Show a => a -> MyType a
```